# C# writing into excel files by using XLWorkbook

Tags: c#, excel

Sample Excel to be imported:

| Data |
| --- |
| First |
| Second |
| Third |

My code at the moment:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{             
    OpenFileDialog ope = new OpenFileDialog();
    ope.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm";
    if (ope.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
        return;
    FileStream stream = new FileStream(ope.FileName, FileMode.Open);
    IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
    DataSet ds = excelReader.AsDataSet();

    int counter = 1;

    foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
    {                
        foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
        {                    
            if (table.Rows.IndexOf(dr) != 0)
            {
                string SINs = Convert.ToString(dr[1]);                   
                textBox7.Text = SINs;
                Console.WriteLine(SINs);
                Console.WriteLine(counter);

                var wb = new XLWorkbook();
                var worksheet = wb.Worksheets.Add("SINS");
                for (int i=1; i<counter; i++)
                {
                    worksheet.Cell(i, 1).Value = SINs;
                }
                wb.SaveAs("C:\\Users\\WYCHIN\\Desktop\\YONG_TEMP\\DHL API\\Sins.xlsx");
                counter++;
            }                          
        }                
    }
}
```

What i wanted to be imported into the Sins.xlsx without header:

| No Header |
| --- |
| First |
| Second |
| Third |

What i get from my code above:

| No header |
| --- |
| Third |
| Third |
| Third |

Did i messed up my logic here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, it's your logic issue, you conducted looking up each data row, then do save everytime, of course the last will be kept. Not only that, foreach `DataRow dr `  but get `table.Rows.IndexOf(dr)` to check everytime is also unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your kind assistance and suggestion, i have solved it by doing modification at the code below.

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
     OpenFileDialog ope = new OpenFileDialog();
     ope.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm";
     if (ope.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
     {
          return;
     }                
     FileStream stream = new FileStream(ope.FileName, FileMode.Open);
     IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
     DataSet ds = excelReader.AsDataSet();

     int counter = 1;
     var wb = new XLWorkbook();
     var worksheet = wb.Worksheets.Add("SINS");

     foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
     {                
          foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
          {
               if(table.Rows.IndexOf(dr) != 0)
               {
                    string SINs = Convert.ToString(dr[1]);                           
                    textBox7.Text = SINs;

                    Console.WriteLine(SINs);   //debug line
                    Console.WriteLine(counter);   //debug line

                    worksheet.Cell(counter, 1).Value = SINs;   //writes to the excel

                    counter++;
                }
          }                
     }            

     wb.SaveAs("C:\\Users\\WYCHIN\\Desktop\\YONG_TEMP\\DHL API\\Sins.xlsx");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should take lines

```
var wb = new XLWorkbook();
var worksheet = wb.Worksheets.Add("SINS");
```

and

```
wb.SaveAs("C:\\Users\\WYCHIN\\Desktop\\YONG_TEMP\\DHL API\\Sins.xlsx");
```

out of the loop.

For each row you're creating new worksheet and saving `xlsx` file.
I cannot test it (I don't have your `DataTable`s), but you should try something like this:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{             
    OpenFileDialog ope = new OpenFileDialog();
    ope.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm";
    if (ope.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
        return;
    FileStream stream = new FileStream(ope.FileName, FileMode.Open);
    IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
    DataSet ds = excelReader.AsDataSet();

    int counter = 1;
    var wb = new XLWorkbook();
    var worksheet = wb.Worksheets.Add("SINS");

    foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
    {                
        foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
        {                    
            string SINs = Convert.ToString(dr[1]);                   
            textBox7.Text = SINs;
            Console.WriteLine(SINs);
            Console.WriteLine(counter);

            for (int i=1; i<counter; i++)
            {
                worksheet.Cell(i, 1).Value = SINs;
            }

            counter++;
            
        }                
    }

    wb.SaveAs("C:\\Users\\WYCHIN\\Desktop\\YONG_TEMP\\DHL API\\Sins.xlsx");
}
```

EDIT: removed unnecessary checking for row index.